# Write to Mysql DB from bash in utf-8

Tags: mysql, bash, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have got problem to write to mysql DB in utf-8 encoding. My application is little bit complicated, so I will try to be as specific as possible. (My aplication requires Slovak special charaters (there are in utf-8) like ľščťžýáí etc.

I am running debian. I believe that my locale is correctly set, but to be sure:

```
root@radiator:/var/scripts# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=sk_SK.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=sk_SK.UTF-8:cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sk_SK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have bash script which should write text (in Slovak language to DB.) (the first hash character is because debian don't know to work with BOM, still don't know how to deal with it )

```
#
#!/bin/bash
table=$1
cycle=$2
sstart=$3
eend=$4
dbtext=$(cat /var/www/vids/$5/vars/$5.recogn.p.tmp2)

qry="INSERT INTO  \`video\`.\`$table\` (\`DB_ID\` , \`LNX_ID\` , \`STIME\` , \`ETIME\` , \`TEXT\` ) VALUES ( NULL , '$cycle', '$sstart', '$eend', '$dbtext');"

mysql --host=localhost --database 'video' --user=uzivatel --password=heslo << eof
$qry
eof
```

This is content of mentioned tmp2 file (encoding of this file is utf-8):

```
Tá žena držal poznali poznal jeho rodičov poznali podsvetie hodváb ulsteru mám ostatných tak veľmi dobre ako boli pre nato že sa bude vydávať ale skóre nevyšlo to potom zas nasťahovala.
```

And in phpmyadmin it look like :

```
TÃ¡ Å¾ena drÅ¾al poznali poznal jeho rodiÄov poznali podsvetie hodvÃ¡b ulsteru mÃ¡m ostatnÃ½ch tak veÄ¾mi dobre ako boli pre nato Å¾e sa bude vydÃ¡vaÅ¥ ale skÃ³re nevyÅ¡lo to potom zas nasÅ¥ahovala.
```

(encoding in this field is utf8_slovak_ci ) (google chrome encoding is utf8) .

It took me whole day to google this and I don't know what is problem.
Could you please help me ? I know that you are the best.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your UTF-8 input is being interpreted in a single-byte encoding at some point, most likely by `mysql` itself because the database connection may default to `latin1`.

Try adding `--default-character-set=utf8` to your `mysql` call. (Alternatively, a `SET NAMES utf8` put before the query should have the same effect.)

Comment: Pekka you are the God to me now.. :) thank you works well.. !